# Probability that $\operatorname{Erlang}(2,\mu _2)$ is greater than $\exp(\mu _1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, gamma-distribution

I'm trying to work out that, given that $X\sim \exp(\mu_1)$ and $Y\sim \operatorname{Erlang}(2,\mu _2)$, what is $\mathbb{P}(X<Y)$?
So far I have:
$$\mathbb{P}(X<Y)=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X<t \mid Y\in dt)\mathbb{P}(Y \in dt)$$
$$=\int_0^{\infty}(1-e^{-\mu _1t}){\mu _2}^2te^{-\mu _2t}dt$$
I can do this integral, but it looks like it will be a great big mess. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Are we assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: Yes they are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral isn't so hard to compute:

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}(1-e^{-\mu _1t})\mu_2(\mu_2 t)e^{-\mu _2t}\, \mathsf dt 
&= \mu_2\int_0^\infty t\mu_2 e^{-\mu_2 t}\,\mathsf dt - \frac{\mu_2^2}{\mu_1+\mu_2}\int_0^\infty (\mu_1+\mu_2)te^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)t}\,\mathsf dt\\
&=\mu_2\cdot\frac1{\mu_2} -\frac{\mu_2^2}{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^2}\\
&= \frac{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^2-\mu_2^2}{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^2}\\
&= \frac{\mu_1^2+2\mu_1\mu_2}{(\mu_1+\mu_2)^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: @msm Thanks for catching the typo.